# lambda calculus, normal order, normal form,

Tags: lambda-calculus, evaluation-strategy

In lambda calculus, if a term has normal form, normal order reduction strategy will always produce it.

I just wonder how to prove the above proposition strictly?

Comment: I think you mean church rosser "theorem"

Answer (score 5):

The result you mention is a corollary of the so called standardization theorem, stating that for any reduction sequence M->N there is another "standard" one between the same terms M and N, where you execute redexes in leftmost outermost order. The proof is not so trivial, and there are several different approaches in the literature. I add a short bibliography below.

The recent proof by Kashima [5](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2586765) (see also [1](http://moscova.inria.fr/~levy/pubs/13standard.pdf)) has the advantage of not using the notion of residual and of being based on purely inductive techniques. It is also good for formalization [2](http://www.is.titech.ac.jp/~kashima/pub/C-145.pdf), but unless you are not already confident with the subject, it is not particularly instructive.

The general idea behind standardization is the following.
Suppose to have two redexes R and S, where S is in leftmost outermost position with respect to R, and consider the following reduction:

```
                R      S
             M  ->  P  ->  N
```

Then, you can start firing S, instead, but in this way you can possibly duplicate (or erase) the redex R. These redexes, that are essentially what remains of R after firing S, are called residuals, and are usually indicated as R/S (read: residuals of R after S). 
So, the basic lemma is that

```
             R S = S (R/S)
```

In order to use it for standardization, we need to generalize R to an arbitrary sequence ρ (that we may assume to be standard, with no redex in leftmost outermost position w.r.t. S). It is still true that

```
         (*) ρS = S (ρ/S)
```

but what is not so evident is the standardization of (ρ/S). To this aim,
let us observe that ρ was performed before firing S = C[\x.M N], that 
essentially splits the term in three disconnected regions: the context C, M, and N. 
This induces a repartition of ρ in three consecutive sequences:

```
           ρ1   inside M
           ρ2   inside N
           ρ3   inside C
```

(remember that no redex was in leftmost outermost position w.r.t. S).
The only part that can be duplicated (or erased) is ρ2, and the residuals
ρ2-0 ... ρ2-k are easily ordered according to the different positions of 
the k copies of N created by the firing of S. So

```
   S ρ1 ρ2-0 ... ρ2-k ρ_3
```

is the standard version of (*).

Basic bibliography.

[1](http://moscova.inria.fr/~levy/pubs/13standard.pdf) A.Asperti, JJ. Levy. [The cost of usage in the lambda-calculus](http://moscova.inria.fr/~levy/pubs/13standard.pdf). LICS 2013.

[3](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-abstract-standardisation-theorem-Gonthier-L%C3%A9vy/407eba2bbdd093a77c638c942624e6b47426966c) H. P. Barendregt. The Lambda Calculus, North-Holland (1984).

[4](https://jfr.unibo.it/article/view/3392) G.Gonthier,  JJ. Levy,  PA. Mellies. [An abstract standardisation theorem](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-abstract-standardisation-theorem-Gonthier-L%C3%A9vy/407eba2bbdd093a77c638c942624e6b47426966c). LICS  ’92.

[2](http://www.is.titech.ac.jp/~kashima/pub/C-145.pdf) F.Guidi. [Standardization  and  Confluence  in  Pure  Lambda-Calculus 
Formalized for the Matita Theorem Prover](https://jfr.unibo.it/article/view/3392). Journal of Formalized Reasoning
5(1):1–25, 2012.

[5](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2586765)  R.Kashima. [A  proof of the standardization theorem in lambda-calculus](http://www.is.titech.ac.jp/~kashima/pub/C-145.pdf).
Technical Report C-145,, Tokyo Institute of Technology, 2000.

[6] JW. Klop. Combinatory  Reduction  Systems.  PhD  thesis,  CWI,
Amsterdam, 1980.

[7] G.Mitschke. The standardisation theorem for the lambda-calculus.
Z. Math.Logik. Grundlag. Math, 25:29–31, 1979

[8] M.Takahashi. Parallel reductions in lambda-calculus.
Information and Computation 118, pp.120-127, 1995.

[9] H. Xi, [Upper bounds for standardizations and an application](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2586765). Journal of Symboloc Logic 64, pp.291-303, 1999.